# Global Variables in Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way for me to use a functionality similar to what are called [Global Variables](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/variables#Declaringglobalvariables) in the Spark View Engine, but for Razor.

The point of it all lis to be able to define a variable in one section for the title and then being able to set or change the value of that variable later on in another section.

In Spark you would create the variable in a section kind of like this (incomplete code for example purposes):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <global type='string' Title='"Site Name"'/>
    <title>${Title}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><use content="view"/></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then you could set it in a different view or section or whatever:

```
<set Title='product.Name + " - " + Title'/>
```

How would I go about doing something like this in Razor or just solving a similar problem if I have the wrong approach ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `ViewBag.Title` inside the layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Site Name</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then define this variable inside the view:

```
@model AppName.Models.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Following on the comments question about default values you could use sections.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("Title"))
    {
        RenderSection("Title")
    }
    else 
    {
        <text>Some default title</text>
    }
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then inside your view you could redefine the section if you will:

```
@section Title {
    <text>some redefined title here</text>
}
```

Comment: That seems work, but it seems that if I set the value of title in the layout (like if I want to have a default one) and then "change" it in the view, it keeps the first value set. Now if I don't set it on the layout, it takes the value set on the view. Any idea how to work around that ? Thanks!

Comment: @Lilitu88, please see my update about the `IsSectionDefined` and `RenderSection` methods.

Comment: Sections are not necessary in this case. You could just have the following expression in your view `@(ViewBag.Title ?? "Default Title")`

Answer (score 0):

You can set and then overwrite this value in view as well using this approach:

```
 @PageData["myTitle"] = "Title 1";
```